# I have problem displaying the lists of users and posts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have users and posts on my database, I would like to display the total number of users and posts in the database. But when I click the login link I get undefined variable.

I have gotten the lists of users and posts but it does not work when I click the login link

**PostController for the Homepage**

```php
public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $news= News::latest()->paginate(15);
       $users = User::latest();
       $totalNews = News::count();
       $totalUsers = User::count(); 
        return view('pages.welcome',compact('news', 'tags', 'users'))->with(['total'=>$totalNews])->with(['sum'=>$totalUsers]);
    }
```

**NewsController for the posts list**

```php
public function index(Request $request, $tag=null)
    {   
        if($tag){
            $tag=Tag::where('name',$tag)->first();
            $news=$tag->news()->latest()->paginate(15);
        }else{
            $news= News::latest()->paginate(15);
        }
        $totalNews = News::count();
        $totalUsers = User::count();
        return view('categories.news',compact(['news','tag']))->with(['sum'=>$totalUsers])->with(['total'=>$totalNews]);
    }
```

**Blade**

```html
@guest
   Welcome, Guest
     <br>
     <b>Stats:</b> {{$sum}}  Members, {{$total}} Topics
     <br>
     <b>Date:</b> {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}}
     <br>
     <b><li><a href="{{ route('login')}}">Login</a></li></b> |
        @if (Route::has('register'))
          <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
        @endif

       @else
Welcome, <a href="{{route('user_profile',auth()->user())}}">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a> 
       <br>
       <b>Stats:</b>  Members,  Topics
       <br>
      <b>Date:</b> {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}}
      <br>
      <br>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> {{ __('Logout') }}</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
</form>
@endguest
</ul>
```

I expect the results to output but it does not when I click on the login link

Comment: I have done that now

Comment: Please format better your code with the indentation. its very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking like these

```php
     @guest
        <b>Stats:</b> Log into see stats
     @else
       <b>Stats:</b> {{ User::all()->count() }}  Members, {{ Topics::all()->count()  }} Topics
     @endif
     <br>
     <b>Date:</b> {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}}
     <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The section starting with `@guest` only outputs when the user is not logged in, and this is where you decided to put your `<b>Stats:</b> {{$sum}}  Members, {{$total}} Topics` statements.

To fix, move or copy this line to inside the `@else` section, or outside the `@guest`/`@endguest` block altogether.

```php
<!-- displays for all users since it's outside the guest block -->
<b>Stats:</b> {{$sum}}  Members, {{$total}} Topics
<br>
<b>Date:</b> {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A') }}

<ul>
    @guest
        Welcome, Guest
        <li><a href="{{ route('login')}}">Login</a></li></b> |
        @if (Route::has('register'))
            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
        @endif

    @else
        Welcome, <a href="{{ route('user_profile', auth()->user()) }}">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a> 
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> {{ __('Logout') }}</a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
        </form>
    @endguest
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the "tags"-compact in your PostController for the Homepage, it is missing and because of that you get the undefined variable error.

and use a "beautifier" plugin for your CodeEditor ;)